# My variable isn't getting valye as expected

Tags: c++, variables, pi

Why this code isn't working as expected?

When I start debugging proizvod is always on 1, bat it should be

```
 0.75 = 1 - (1/4) and so on.
```

My code is this

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int _tmain()
{   
    int plusminus = 1, brojac = 0;
    double proizvod = 1; 
    double pi;
    while (brojac < 6)
    {
        plusminus = plusminus + 2;
        if (brojac % 2 == 0)
        {
            proizvod = proizvod - ( 1 / plusminus );
        }
        else
        {
            proizvod = proizvod + ( 1 / plusminus );
        }
        pi = proizvod * 4;
        brojac++;
    }
    cout << "Broj PI sa 6 decimala je " << pi << "  ." << endl;
}
```

Comment: You are dividing integers. They aren't automagically converted to `double`. (`1/3 == 0`)

Comment: Format your code with a modicum of sense.

Answer (score 1):

`1 / plusminus` can only be 0 because `plusminus` is an integer > 1 (you increment it by 2 at the start) so you're experiencing integer division.

Example of fix: `1.0 / plusminus`